# get sh to execute the commands inside from a PDF compiled with LaTeX

Tags: bash, scripts, pdf, latex

I have a solution of a PDE in an executable file called `demo_poisson`, which I can double click to get the window to open and show the graph of the solution. I think it works with VTK but I'm not sure. The solution is obtained with FEniCS.

Now, in a beamer presentation compiled with TexMaker I want to have a "click here" hyperef to my solution, so that i click it and the solution appears.
This is done by using the command

```
\href{run:demo_poisson}{Click here}
```

This command works fine for opening PDF files, for instance, but with my executable, the PDF reader objects "There is no application registered to open this file".

So I tried creating a `test.sh` file containing the command to open my solution

```
#!/bin/sh
/home/me/Documents/Project/Presentation/demo_poisson
```

and after `chmod +x test.sh`, running

```
\href{run:test.sh}{Click here}
```

opens geany and shows the two lines of code.

Out of desperation I created a .desktop file with the order of executing test.sh and I can double click on it and it works, but I can't give the command to open it from within the PDF.

Any idea on how I can get the test.sh file to actually execute the commands inside, instead of showing the code, or equivalently to open my `demo_poisson` from a PDF?

Comment: What is the output of `file demo_poisson`? What permissions are set?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it would help, if you could provide a full pdf example for that.

But to be honest, I could think of good reasons why the creators of PDF restricted the execution of commands from a PDF. If it was easy to start any command, one could build nice trojan PDFs that penetrate systems.
Because so far, I haven't heard of something like that, I guess it is not possible (because malware producers are very creative, and most likely would have used it already).

But have you thought of creating a javascript version for your demo and embed it in a HTLM file? I guess it would be much easier to embed a hyperlink to such a HTML solution in your pdf (you could just store the HTML locally).